# how to install lxqt on ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: command-line, server, software-installation, lxqt

I have a Ubuntu Server that I want to turn into a LAMP server. I would like to do a little bit of web development on it as well so I would like to add a very lightweight desktop environment. So far the least resource heavy desktop environment that I can seem to find is LXQT DE. I run the install by typing into terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install lxqt
```

and it runs but it after it is finished and I reboot it - it just goes back to terminal. When I try running the install again, it says that LXQT was installed properly - how do I get it to load automatically in LXQT from boot up what am I missing? If someone has a link to a website that give me step by step instructions it would be much appreciated. I have tried to use my google-foo but have come up empty.

Comment: No need to reinstall lxqt. Normally you would install a DM, display manager as well. Examples of display managers are : lightdm, gdm,sddm. Another way is to log in, and then start the desktop environment manually. With XFCE4 desktop that can be done by running "startxfce4" at the command line. Perhaps LXQt has something similar ? Even this is not Ubuntu focused, it might still be helpful for your question : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXQt  And did you read this page as well ? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/LXQt

Comment: Hey @albertj that was my first thought - but lxqt comes with sddm - so it should work right?

Comment: Reuben, sddm is the default DM for KDE I read. Maybe it needs some more software or making systemd clear that sddm should be started at boot time ?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/LXQt -> There is a part about sddm failing. Perhaps try their suggestion ?

Comment: Just to add : A few weeks ago I played with LXQt in a virtual machine, because I was curious about it and I liked the screenshots. I forgot the details though. For a light weight desktop you can also choose Xubuntu or Lubuntu. That can be install along side Ubuntu desktop. For example : sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop would install XFCE4 as desktop environment.  And that should give you a working DM as well.

Comment: this time I tried running the install of SDDM first so i ran `sudo apt install sddm` and then I ran `sudo systemctl start sddm.service` followed by `sudo systemctl enable sddm.service` then I ran `sudo apt install lxqt` it still isn't doing what I want, when I look at the status of the sddm service by typing `sudo systemctl status sddm.service` I get the message Failed to start display server process. Does anyone have any idea what this could mean?

Answer (score 3):

LXQt meta package did not include XORG and any display manager.

**Try :**

***1#***
Run command

`sudo apt install xorg sddm lxqt`

and reboot then you can select LXQt from SDDM login screen.

.

***2#*** 
If you have installed XORG, LXQt, SDDM (or any x-display-manager).

Check in /usr/share/xsessions/ there should be a file lxqt.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=LXQt
Exec=startlxqt
TryExec=lxqt-session
Type=Application
```

It's worked on Ubuntu 16.04, but, do not install LXQt with Lubuntu in the same PC.
It cause a lot of problem.

Answer (score 2):

So I logged into the #LXQT IRC channel and they confirmed to me that LXQT doesn't work with 16.04 for some reason. So I either need to upgrade to 17.04 (beta at the moment) or not use it. I find it a little crazy that the LTS version isn't supported but it's their software not mine.